# Can't update the node version using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I ran the command `npm  install -g n` to then install the latest node version, but this came up:

```
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-11-12T19_56_01_886Z-debug.log
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean update node version using npm ? npm can be used to install and update npm packages not node version itself

Comment: Download the installer for the latest version and run it. NPM is not meant to update node, only to install or update new libraries.

Comment: Also this indicates that you are trying to run npm without sudo . Check this out 
https://docs.w3cub.com/npm/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions